# calling an object method from another method not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, object-initializers

Suppose I have the following coding scenario:

```
export const test = () => {
    return (
        var1,
        var2,
        var3
    ) => {
        return Object.freeze({
            getVarOne: () => var1,
            getVarTwo: () => var2,
            getVarThree: () => var3,
            total: () => var1 + var2 + var3,
            squareTotal: () => Math.pow(total(), 2)
        })
    }
}

let obj1 = test();
let obj2 = obj1(1, 2, 3);
let obj3 = obj2.squareTotal();
```

What is a way I can access the total method from the squareTotal method?  I keep getting undefined for the total method call.

Comment: What is `total` that you use in `Math.pow`? You didn't define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an undefined `total` function called as argument to `Math.pow`. If you intended to call the *member* of the object, then you need to specify that, as currently, it is a *variable* reference, not a *property*.

You can use `this`, but you must make the method a standard `function` instead of an arrow function -- you can use the ES6 object method notation (omitting the `function` keyword):

```js
const test = () => {
    return (
        var1,
        var2,
        var3
    ) => {
        return Object.freeze({
            getVarOne: () => var1,
            getVarTwo: () => var2,
            getVarThree: () => var3,
            total: () => var1 + var2 + var3,
            squareTotal() { return Math.pow(this.total(), 2) }   
        })
    }
}

let obj1 = test();
let obj2 = obj1(1, 2, 3);
let obj3 = obj2.squareTotal();

console.log(obj3);
```

Comment: What is squareTotal needed to use await/async using this same syntax or would I have to use the function keyword?  How would that alter the syntax?

Comment: You can just prefix `async`, like `async squareTotal() { return Math.pow(this.total(), 2) }`

Answer (score 0):

From inside of `squareTotal()` when called as you show in your example, you can do:

```
this.total()
```

`this` will be `obj2` which is the frozen object that has the `total` method on it.  But, you also need to stop using arrow functions for any methods that wish to reference your own object because arrow functions use the lexical value of `this`, not the called object value of `this`.

This will work with the two changes 1) change to `this.total()` and 2) change `squareTotal()` to regular function - not arrow function so it has the proper value of `this`:

```js
const test = () => {
    return (
        var1,
        var2,
        var3
    ) => {
        return Object.freeze({
            getVarOne: () => var1,
            getVarTwo: () => var2,
            getVarThree: () => var3,
            total: () => var1 + var2 + var3,
            squareTotal: function() {
                return Math.pow(this.total(), 2);
            },
        })
    }
}

let fn = test();
let obj2 = fn(1, 2, 3);
let result = obj2.squareTotal();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`total` is not a global function that you can call like `total()`. If you want to access the `total` method from the `object` you are returning, call `this.total()`. But make sure to not use arrow function expression.

You can use the below code:

```js
const test = () => {
    return (
        var1,
        var2,
        var3
    ) => {
        return Object.freeze({
            getVarOne: () => var1,
            getVarTwo: () => var2,
            getVarThree: () => var3,
            total: () => var1 + var2 + var3,
            squareTotal: function() {return Math.pow(this.total(), 2) }
        })
    }
}    

let obj1 = test();
let obj2 = obj1(1, 2, 3);
let obj3 = obj2.squareTotal();

console.log(obj3);
```

Reason for changing from arrow function is that, arrow functions take `this` from the lexical scope of their declaration. Here it would have belonged to the `window object`. For any other method, `this` depends on how they are invoked(here they are invoked by the object). [Relevant SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access properties within the same object, don't use arrow functions: they can't use the objects' [scope](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-scope/). Here is a simplification of you factory function, where `total` is a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and `squareTotal` a function expression for the instance.

```js
const test = () => {
  return (var1, var2, var3) => {
    return Object.freeze({
      get total() {
        return var1 + var2 + var3;
        // ^ because the object is frozen
        //   var1 ... var3 don't have to be
        //   part of the object. Values are
        //   retrieved from closed over 
        //   parameter values
      },
      squareTotal() {
        return Math.pow(this.total, 2);
      },
    });
  };
}

const obj1 = test();
const obj2 = obj1(1, 2, 3);
console.log(`obj2.squareTotal(): ${obj2.squareTotal()}`);

// btw: because of the closure, the factory can 
// be simplified to a one liner too:
const test1a = () => (v1, v2, v3) => Object.freeze({
    squareTotal: () => Math.pow(v1 + v2 + v3, 2), });
const obj1a = test1a()(1, 2, 3);
console.log(`obj1a.squareTotal(): ${obj1a.squareTotal()}`);

// note: getter is not useful in a frozen object,
// but if the properties may change later it can be
// because in that case 'total' always gives the current
// total

const test2 = () => {
  return (var1, var2) => {
    return {
      var1,
      var2,
      get total() {
        return this.var1 + this.var2;
      },
      squareTotal() {
        return Math.pow(this.total, 2);
      },
    };
  };
};
const x = test2()(1, 2);
console.log(`x.sqareTotal(): ${x.squareTotal()}`);
x.var2 = 15;
console.log(`x.var2: ${x.var2}; x.squareTotal():  ${x.squareTotal()}`);
```